# Strokes broken or shape going underneath others once clicked - Raphael.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, svg, raphael

I made this [map](http://mastercaweb.u-strasbg.fr/0910/Maxxim/france.html), following the demo on Raphaël website.
I want each shape (département) to be clickable and lead to a page.
I put a link, for example, on a yellow shape, more or less in the center of the map.

Here it's how it goes:
Not clicked, the shape looks great, I click it, it leads the page, perfect!
I click the previous arrow on my browser to go back and hover again that same shape, and it behaves really weird. The strokes seem broken or the shape going underneath the other ones ([details here](http://mastercaweb.u-strasbg.fr/0910/Maxxim/before-after.jpg)). Do you know what's happening?

Also, I would like to have your opinion and feedback about your experience with the map (usability and compatibility with browsers (IE?) mostly).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it looks weird is because by adding a link to the element, Raphael wraps the `<path>` element (that defines the département shape) inside an `<a href="">`. But its `toFront()` method still works on the `<path>`, so that now just pushes it to the front of the `<a>`, instead of to the front of the entire set of départements. In other words, `.toFront()` doesn't work anymore.

That looks like a bug in Raphael to me, actually. I'm not sure how to fix it, other than replacing each occurrence of `.toFront()` you're using by a function that checks if the node has an `<a>` parent, and if it does, move *that* to the front instead (by reinserting it into the DOM).

#### Also,

It's broken in IE in a different way.

I think whoever made that demo already knew about it, because the `if(current)` block in the `mouseover` fixes it on the Australia example. But the scaling and stroke-width animation you added basically also need to be reset there.

If you replace that `if(current)` block by the following it should work:

```
if (current && current != departement) {
    fra[current].animate({
        fill: "#333",
        stroke: "#666",
        "stroke-width": 1
    }, 500);
    fra[current].scale(1,1)
    document.getElementById(current).style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With some help, I managed to fix it, I think. You might want to check this [page](http://mastercaweb.u-strasbg.fr/0910/Maxxim/france2.html)

Comment: Works for me... There's another problem in IE, though. I've updated my answer with a fix for that.

Comment: Thank you very much mercator. I updated the demo if you want to take a look.